# same-origin iframe contents returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, undefined

I'm trying to access a same-origin iframe that I've created via userscript. After generating the iframe, the HTML looks like (with the `src` truncated):

```
<table id="addUsers">
    <tr id="auBody">
        <td id="iframeCell">
            <iframe id="searchArea" src="/webapps/blackboard/execute/userManager?..."></iframe>
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

No matter what I do, its contents always return null or undefined. I've even created a button for testing, with the following listener:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {    
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#searchArea');
    console.log('--TESTING IFRAME--');
    console.log(':: SRC: ' + iframe.getAttribute('src').substring(0, 40) + '...');
    iframe.contentWindow ?
        console.log(':: iframe.contentWindow exists with length: ' + iframe.contentWindow.length) :
        console.error(':: iframe.contentWindow does not exist.')
    ;
    iframe.contentWindow.document ?
        console.log(':: iframe.contentWindow.document exists with length: ' + iframe.contentWindow.document.length) :
        console.error(':: iframe.contentWindow.document does not exist.')
    ;
    iframe.contentDocument ?
        console.log(':: iframe.contentDocument exists with length: ' + iframe.contentDocument.length) :
        console.error(':: iframe.contentDocument does not exist.')
    ;
});
```

Once the iframe is loaded, I click the button and get this output:

```
--TESTING IFRAME--
:: SRC: /webapps/blackboard/execute/userManager?...
:: iframe.contentWindow exists with length: 0
:: iframe.contentWindow.document exists with length: undefined
:: iframe.contentDocument exists with length: undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? I was always able to do this without trouble in jQuery, but I'm still trying to pick up vanilla JS more heavily.

Comment: Are you getting any server errors from the iframe request or is it successful?

Comment: @CBroe `$grab` is not a jQuery function; it's a shorthand function I wrote for on document.querySelector() -- which returns an element. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @bob0the0mighty No errors are showing for me. Where should I be looking?

Comment: in your browser's developer console. F12 brings it up on most in Windows. There you should be able to look at the network requests. Your iframe will have it's own request for your userManager page. You'll also be able to use the console as a REPL.

Comment: @bob0the0mighty Oh, just the network error logs. Nope -- no errors there whatsoever, actually.

Comment: Does iframe.window do anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101708/discussion-between-bob0the0mighty-and-cliff).